# Intellij IDEA & PyCharm - Links between lines of code only known at runtime

Tags: javascript, python, debugging, intellij-idea, pycharm

This question is about Intellij IDEs but also about IDEs in general, if necessary to answer. Let's say I have multiple Python scripts in a project. In one file, I might have something like this:

```
with Switch(command) as case:
    if case('endpoint1'):
        print('do something')
    if case.default:
        pass
```

and in another script I have this, which pings the first script:

```
send({'command': 'endpoint1'})
```

Is there some IDE feature that would let me link the two lines of code since one is directly related to the other? That or some way to link the string literal `endpoint1`? Either ways or both, maybe? The point would be so that I could easily jump from the calling code `send` to the receiving end `case('endpoint1')` without having to manually search for the string or depend on a comment. Is there a way?

Note: In certain cases, even the debugger won't be able to make such a link because it could be an HTTP request or RPC that links them. The intention is to manually make the link so it's easy to jump from one to the other while editing.

Comment: You can try using [bookmarks with mnemonics](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#use_bookmarks) or [favorite groups](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-your-project-favorites.html).

Comment: @CrazyCoder those are good. Not exactly what I'm looking for but thanks for them.

Comment: `Code Reading Note` plugin can sort of do it. Let's you bookmark a list of code lines I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way for the IDE to link from one diectly to the other with your code looking the same as it does now without writing your own plugin, which I would not recommend. However, there are some ways that you could change your code that may help you.

### Option 1: link to a common definition

If both scripts import the same script containing the definition `endpoint1 = 'endpoint1'`, then you use `send({'command': endpoint1})` and `if case(endpoint1):`, then you can jump from one usage to the definition then to the other usage.

### Option 2: define the logic using inheritance rather than a 'switch' statement

This option will give behaviour closer to what you want. Here you use a class to represent each possible value that you may send or switch over, and implement the logic that was previously in your switch statement as a method in each sub-class.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class AbstractEndpoint(ABC):
    def do_stuff(self):
        # default
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def serialize(self):
        pass


class Endpoint1(AbstractEndpoint):
    def do_stuff(self):
        print('do something')

    def serialize(self):
        return 'endpoint1'


class Endpoint2(AbstractEndpoint):
    def do_stuff(self):
        print('do something else')

    def serialize(self):
        return 'endpoint2'


class Endpoint3(AbstractEndpoint):
    # does not override do_stuff, so default behaviour is used

    def serialize(self):
        return 'endpoint3'


deserialize_dict = {'endpoint1': Endpoint1, 'endpoint2': Endpoint2, 'endpoint3': Endpoint3}


def deserialize(string_repr):
    return deserialize_dict[string_repr]()


e = Endpoint1()

# prints 'do something'
e.do_stuff()

# convert to and from string
e_serialize = e.serialize()
print(deserialize(e_serialize))

# does nothing because it doesn't override default behaviour
Endpoint3().do_stuff()
```

Then you would modify your send function to serialize objects so you can write `send({'command': Endpoint1()})`, and deserialize on the other end. This will let you navigate directly from the send to whichever class you are sending, and back again using the definition and usages navigation.

Comment: That's a decent point for some situations. There are still many cases that won't help though. There are many I work with that are in 2 different languages. I'm still searching through the plugin repo btw. Is there a reason you don't recommend writing a new one? I've never written one.

Comment: @xendi It just seems like a lot of work. I've never written one either, so maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer. I may offer a better answer in the future if I decide to create a plugin. I really want to. I'm just not too big on Java but we'll see.

Comment: @xendi if you don't like Java you could try Kotlin or maybe Jython